# How to change tmp directory in yarn

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have written a MR job and have run it in local mode with following configuration settings

```
mapred.local.dir=<<local directory having good amount of space>>
fs.default.name=file:///
mapred.job.tracker=local
```

on Hadoop 1.x

Now I am using Hadoop 2.x and the same Job I am running with the same Configuration settings, but I am getting error :

```
Disk Out of Space
```

Is it that If I switch from Hadoop 1.x to 2.x (using Hadoop-2.6 jars), the same Configuration Settings to change the Tmp Dir not work.??

What are the new Settings to configure the "tmp" directory of MR1 (mapred API) on Hadoop 2.6.

Kindly advice.

Regards
Cheers :))

Answer (score 1):

Many properties in 1.x have been deprecated and replaced with new properties in 2.x.

**mapred.child.tmp** has been replaced by **mapreduce.task.tmp.dir**

**mapred.local.dir** has been replaced by **mapreduce.cluster.local.dir**

Have a look at complete list of deprecated properties and new equivalent properties at [Apache website link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by setting

```
mapreduce.cluster.local.dir=<<local directory having good amount of space>>
```