# Change tmp directory while running yarn jar command

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am running an MR job using **yarn jar** command and it creates a temporary jar in **/tmp** folder which fills up the entire disk space. I want to redirect the path of this jar to some other folder where I have more disk space. On this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473169/how-to-change-tmp-directory-in-yarn), I came to know that we can change the path by setting the property **mapred.local.dir** for hadoop version 1.x. I am using the following command to run the jar

```
yarn jar myjar.jar MyClass myyml.yml arg1 -D mapred.local.dir="/grid/1/uie/facts"
```

The above argument mapred.local.dir doesn't change the path and it is still creating the jar in tmp folder.

Comment: What version of Hadoop are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the hack to not write the unjar file to /tmp folder. Apparently, it is not a configurable behaviour, so we can avoid the use of 'hadoop jar' or 'yarn jar'(RunJar utility) by invoking instead with the generated classpath:

java -cp $(hadoop classpath):my-fat-jar-with-all-dependencies.jar
your.app.mainClass

[1. Reference link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-user/201410.mbox/%3CCAOcnVr2bd5mq+tEyrzpY5WWsaiLuvikme+qNVxUmiA4RvfTMkA@mail.gmail.com%3E)